# Blank/Black Screen on AppleTV when mirrored from iMac

Tags: appletv, airplay

Using macOS Sierra 10.12.5, iMac 27-inch Mid 2011, AppleTV Model A1469 7.2.2 (8015)
Connected via WiFi

I have an Apple TV that used to work, however, now whenever I mirror or extend my display from my iMac it only shows a blank/black screen with audio.

I found this post, [Apple TV Black screen (OS X Yosemite )](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181556/apple-tv-black-screen-os-x-yosemite) however, the solutions there did not work for me, and I am not sure how it worked for the OP.

I also found [How to Fix an Apple TV with a Blank Screen](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2347105/fix-apple-blank-screen.html) and reset my Apple TV to factory settings, but still the same problem persists.

The audio works fine and I can switch between internal speakers and the AppleTV but there's no video on the AppleTV.

Any ideas at all are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Please include your iMac model/year and what version of macOS you are currently using.

Comment: Please also include your Apple TV model and its firmware version. Is your Apple TV connected to your network via Wi-Fi?

Comment: Have you rebooted your entire network? Turn off or disable wifi on all connected devices, then do whatever you need to do to reset your internet router and wi-fi transmitter, (usually just a power cycle of the equipment,) then restart or enable wi-fi devices. As an experiment: what happens when you hard-wire (ethernet) the iMac and the ATV through a switch (router, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, The AppleTV is accessing the internet with no problems, I can tell from the main menu

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while using an Apple TV to connect a TV to my MacBook Pro (via LAN) and playing around with the different display modes as it suddenly stopped working.

Unfortunately, I don't remember any details any more but (after several failed attempts) I solved it by explicitly selecting **Off** in System Preferences/Display/Monitor/Dropdown Box *Airport-Monitor* (maybe detaching and reattaching the ethernet cable and/or turning off/on Apple TV were also involved) and reselecting Apple TV again.

This might be important, as deliberately selecting might have reset and/or stored parameters, which may explain why some people experience negative results.

Sorry, if this was too less of information.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with mid 2011 27 iMac. Fix for me was unisntalling the app called "Duet". It's a display mirroring software to iPad.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you. I recommend commenting on the original question and asking if they had Duet installed. Your answer is only valid in cases where Duet is installed (and is the cause of the issue).